# Why is my array working for emailing but not sharing

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have an array of email address that works for MailApp.SendEmail but not for addViewers

Can anyone shed some light on this?

```
function exportSpreadsheet() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var filename = "Copy" + ss.getName();
  var sheetCopy = ss.copy(filename);
  sheetCopy.addViewers(emailTo)
  var message = "yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy";  
  var subject = "xxxx"    
  var contacts = ss.getSheetByName("Contacts");
  var numRows = contacts.getLastRow();
  var emailTo = contacts.getRange(2, 2, numRows, 1).getValues();
  MailApp.sendEmail(emailTo, subject, message);
}
```

The whole script attaches the file to the email but I have removed this as I don't think it affects anything.

The emailTo array is on sheet "Contacts" B2:B and all contacts are receiving the email but I cannot find a way to make this work for addViewer?

Comment: What is the **exact** value of `emailTo`?

Comment: Please add a [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the `emailTo` variable was declared **after** it was called.

Move the following code lines after `var emailTo = contacts.getRange(2, 2, numRows, 1).getValues();`

```
var sheetCopy = ss.copy(filename);
sheetCopy.addViewers(emailTo)
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Issue:

[`Spreadsheet#addViewers(String[])`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#addViewers(String)) accepts `String[]` (1 dimensional array of strings) as argument, while `Range#getValues()` returns `Object[][]`(2 dimensional array of objects).

#### Solution:

- Convert 2D array to 1D array
- Convert object to string type

#### Snippet:

```
sheetCopy.addViewers(emailTo.map(function(row){
  return String(row[0]);
}))
```

Comment: In addition to what Ruben [said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57599947) :)

Comment: I'm sorry this is still coming up with invalid email. I have also moved where email to is declared

Comment: @Tom Edit your question to reflect the latest code or ask a new question.

Comment: @TomAdams Another problem on the question code is `contacts.getRange(2, 2, numRows, 1).getValues()`. One way to fix it is `contacts.getRange(2, 2, numRows - 1, 1).getValues()`;